# How to convert last 3 digits of a number to 000?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I convert last 3 digits of a number to 000 ?

For rounding price of items.

For example:

`123456` to `123000`

Please give me a simple solution.

Comment: Instead of immediately closing it, Peter should add more information to the question. @Peter first: what did you try? Where did you get stuck? Could you provide more information? Noone is just gonna create your solution. Just for future questions on SO ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
number - (number % 1000)
```

```js
const number = 123456;
console.log(number - (number % 1000));
```